# Install tar.bz2 archive?

Tags: software-installation, tar

I cannot seem to find out how to install a tar.bz2 file. I've Googled it and I've came across two commands, these did not work. I've changed my directory to my downloads folder `cd ~downloads` after that I've tried these two

```
tar -xjvf Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2 

tar -zxvf Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2
```

and they both gave me the error of

```
tar (child): Sublime: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I couldn't have spelled it wrong, as I copied the name directly from the archive. I'm very new to Linux, so can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `tab to complete` feature, i.e. press tab after partially entering a filename. Check with `file` command to verify if it's indeed a `tar.bz2`.

Comment: @SparKotॐ I typed in tar -zxvf Sublime and pressed tab and didn't work...

Comment: What is the exact name of the file you got from the archive?

Comment: @Anthon Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64

Comment: I searched for it and the name of the archive is "Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2" so what is the name you copied directly from this archive?

Comment: Usually the download folder is "Downloads" not "downloads". Are you sure you are in the right folder?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you're getting is a result of not being able to unzip the file "Sublime".

> tar (child): Sublime: Cannot open: No such file or directory

This is because the filename argument being passed to `tar` is everything up to the first space, `Sublime Text...`. You can wrap it in double quotes so that the shell, Bash, knows you intend to pass the entire string as a filename to `tar`.

```
$ tar -jxvf "Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2"
```

#### Other problems?

*1. File type*

Often times when I download files such as these I like to use the `file` command on them to confirm that they're in fact named correctly.

#### Examples

```
$ file /home/saml/gaffiter.bz2
/home/saml/gaffiter.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k

$ file /etc/ntop/oui.txt.gz
/etc/ntop/oui.txt.gz: gzip compressed data, was "oui.txt", from Unix, last modified: Sun May  6 00:30:01 2012

$ file /home/saml/Downloads/lplinux.tar.bz2
/home/saml/Downloads/lplinux.tar.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k
```

*2. Corrupt download?*

Try re-downloading the file. I just downloaded it and it unpacked just fine.

```
$ wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2.tar.bz2

$ file "Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2"
Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k

$ tar jxvf "Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2"
Sublime Text 2/
Sublime Text 2/Pristine Packages/
Sublime Text 2/Pristine Packages/Lisp.sublime-package
Sublime Text 2/Pristine Packages/TCL.sublime-package
Sublime Text 2/Pristine Packages/Text.sublime-package
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You first have to specify the name of the archive, then the name(s) of the file you want to extract from it. If that name has spaces, you have to quote them.
The filename ending in `.tar.bz2` is the archive.

As I can't know the name you are trying to extract try the following:

```
tar -xjvf  x64.tar.bz2 "Sublime Text 2.0.2"
```

or

```
tar -xjvf  "2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2" "Sublime Text"
```

or

```
tar -xjvf  "Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2" Sublime
```

Comment: None of those worked. You can download the package via their website (which has to be pretty obvious on how to find it).

Comment: You might not now the terminology but "Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2" **is** the archive not a name you copied **from** the archive, that was misleading.

Comment: Then how do I know what's the archive name?

Comment: A file ending in `.tar` is normally the archive. A file ending in `.tar.bz2` is normally a compressed arvhive. The name of this arvhive is "Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2" (the quotes are not part of the name but necessary to show these are not 4 filenames, but just one). The archive also has the names of the files in it. In this case you are extracting all files, you don't need to copy a name from the archive.

Comment: So what do I put?

Comment: is the file really in `~downloads`? Did you do an `ls -l` after `cd ~downloads`?

Answer (score 0):

> tar -xjvf "Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2"

Quotes are *required* because there are spaces in the filename.

Comment: I received the same error after applying the quotes.